# How to I prevent the screen from locking when I want a virtual machine to ungrab my mouse?

Tags: shortcut-keys, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization, lock-screen, qemu

This happens in both KVM with virt-manager as well as VirtualBox.

The key combo to ungrab the mouse from KVM is Control-Option-L on my Apple MacBook Pro keyboard.  Option on Mac keyboards is mapped to the PC-keyboard ALT key.

Control-Alt-L also locks the screen under Ubuntu Unity.

I cannot find a way to edit the key accellerator in either software package.

I don't think this is just the lock screen keyboard accellerator though, because VirtualBox does have a way to configure the ungrab keys.  Because my keyboard doesn't have a righthand Control key. I use F1 to ungrab under VB.  This *also* result in locking the screen.

Answer (score 5):

the issue is the description is a bit misleading (for me as well) ..
ctrl_L .. doesnt mean ctrl+l but the left! ctrl button

so you just have to press ctrl + alt (without any other char) on the left side of the keybord

Comment: They should revise their UX... it's crazy... I tried for quite a while to use left ctrl+alt+L. I was ending up killing the process from a ssh remote session.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your keyboard isn't either sending the correct
keycodes or they're being intercepted by the desktop shell.
You can verify that your key presses mean what you press by
running **xev** in a terminal. Here's me pressing left ctrl + left alt
on my happy hacker keyboard (PC).

> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
>       root 0xbe, subw 0x0, time 675936933, (432,537), root:(2033,590),
>       state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
>       root 0xbe, subw 0x0, time 675937205, (432,537), root:(2033,590),
>       state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

**You can change the key combo that locks the screen**, it's under
System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Lock Screen. You could completely
disable it if you want.

QEMU/KVM, which is what's actually managing the VM, appears to
have several options for setting [focus grabbing](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html) defaults.

> ‘-alt-grab’
>   Use Ctrl-Alt-Shift to grab mouse (instead of Ctrl-Alt).
>
> ‘-ctrl-grab’
>   Use Right-Ctrl to grab mouse (instead of Ctrl-Alt).

Now I'm not sure how you would tell virt-manager to keep this
default but it is easy enough to grab the arguments it's using the
run your VM, run it yourself from the CLI, and just add one of these
switches to see if it addresses your problem. If it works, then write
a simple script to start your VMs that way. Easiest thing to do is
disable the screen lock shortcut and just use the gui to accomplish
that. Good Luck.